# Scala data structure with type safe accessors

Tags: scala, generics, collections, types, type-safety

Please note I am learning Scala so what I suggest may not be the best (idomatic) way of achieving this, therefore I'll describe the problem I'm trying to solve first, then my current implementation!

Problem: Given some input document, e.g. xml or json, create an object `Doc` with its raw contents as a variable, apply a sequence of `FieldExtractors` which extract a number of value, i.e. `Fields`, which are stored on the `Doc` object and can be accessed in a type safe manner later, e.g. `val username: String = doc.getField(UsernameField)`

**N.B** everything must be Serializable so it can be passed over the wire via a particular framework

So, my current attempt:

```
abstract class Field[+T <: Serializable](val name: String, val valueType: Class[T])

trait Fields {
  var fields: mutable.HashMap[Class[Field[Serializable]], Field[Serializable]] = mutable.HashMap()
  def hasField[T <: Serializable](field: Field[T]): Boolean = false
  def getField[T <: Serializable](field: Field[T]): T = fields.get(field).asInstanceOf(T)
  def setField[T <: Serializable](field: Field[T], value: T): Unit = fields.put(field, value)
}

class Doc(val rawData: String) with Fields

abstract class FieldExtractor[+TYPE <: Serializable](val field: Field[TYPE])  {
  def extractField(input: Doc): Option[TYPE]
}
```

But I get all sorts of errors such as:

> Error:(14, 39) inferred type arguments [String] do not conform to method hasField's type parameter bounds [T <: Serializable]
>       val result:Boolean = fieldsObject.hasField(field)
>                                         ^

I'm wondering if maybe I should use Value types instead? Or the https://github.com/mikaelv/strucs project (which seems rather young)? Or whether there's a better approach?

Eventually I'd write something like

```
extractors.foldLeft(doc)((doc, extractor) => doc.setField(field, extractor.extractField(doc); doc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a symptom of Scala having its own `Serializable` class.

`String` (which Scala uses as a synonym for `java.lang.String`) implements **Java's** `java.io.Serializable` whereas your `Field` class has declared the generic bounds using **Scala's** `Serializable` class.

If you change the declaration to this:

```
abstract class Field[+T <: java.io.Serializable](val name: String, val valueType: Class[T])
```

it compiles* and does the type safe get/set checks correctly for me (* using Scala SDK 2.11.7, I had to correct some minor typos).

Note, there's also an error in the `Fields` class.  I think you meant to declare the hash map as:

```
fields: mutable.HashMap[Field[Serializable], Serializable]
```